# Display Multiple Characters in MS-DOS output

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

How do I display multiple characters in a MS-Dos command

So for example, if I want to display everything in a current directory that begins with A, I might type the following command into CMD.

```
dir/b A*
```

But what if I want to display everything A-M? How would I go about telling the computer to display multiple characters?

Comment: what does this have to do with `[powershell]`? plus, what on EARTH are you doing running MS-DOS? [*grin*] i presume you really mean BAT/CMD stuff, not old MS-DOS.

Comment: Yes I mean the new CMD.

Comment: there is no "new CMD" in windows 10. [*grin*] the default shell runs powershell ... not CMD. for instance, the `dir` command in PoSh is actually an alias for `Get-ChildItem` - a PoSh cmdlet, not the CMD command. ///// **_so, please, decide what you actually want to use ... and remove the other items._***

Answer (score 1):

(this is for PowerShell) `ls` command for listing the current directory and after you add `A*`.
so the command is `ls A*`(it will list name starting with `a` as well).
If you want to filter using regular expression

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match 'RegularExpression' }
```

A regular expression for starts with a letter is  `^[A-M]+.`
Change `-Match` to `CMatch` for capital sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cmd` leaves you two possibilities: list files for each desired letter:

```
dir /b a* b* c* d* ... m*
```

which is awkward and inflexible because of hardcoding the list. Even using a `for` loop isn't better:

```
for %a in (a b c d e ... m) do @dir /b %a*
```

This might work fine if you want just two or three letters.

The second (much more flexible and probably faster too) method: get the whole list and just filter it:

```
dir /b | findstr /rib "[a-m]"
```

For not-consecutive letters (a*, b*, m*, n*, x*, y*):

```
dir /b | findstr /rib "[abmnxy]"
```